# Rendering a template with a for/loop from a give json

Tags: python

I wanted to render a template with all the  “nickname” from a given json string.

My JSON:

```
{
  "total_count": 2,
  "items": [
    {
      "nickname": "player A",
      "Game": "COD",
      "score": 1.0
    },
    {
      "nickname": "player B",
      "Game": "Tetris",
      "score": 1.1
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried this logic but didn’t work. How can I do a for/loop and print in the html all the result?

My failing script:

```
    j = json.loads(r.text)["items"]
    return render_template("index.html", len = len(j), j = j)
```

html:

```
{%for i in range(0, len)%} 
    <li>{{html_url[i]}}</li> 
{%endfor%}
```

I wanted all nickname in the html. For example:

player A

player B

Comment: You set argument `j` but it isn't use into `html`. What is `html_url`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem with your code is you are using undefined variable in the rendering page as I don't see `html_url` being defined anywhere in your code. The other issue is you are not pointing to `nickname attr` of the json correctly.

So, instead of looping through the range of numbers equivalent to the no. of items in your list of names, you can just loop through your list and print their nicknames.

Remove the unneeded length from your rendering python code.

```py
j = json.loads(r.text)["items"]
    return render_template("index.html",j=j)
```

loop over the list and return the nickname attr of the list in your template :)))

```html
{%for i in j%} 
    <li>{{i["nickname"]}}</li> 
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: hey :) sorry for not explaning i just added the explanation.

Comment: glad to know your problem is fixed.